# How do I test the returned value in Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, tdd

I have a simple function that I want to test with Jest. I have read https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions many many times but I'm not sure whats going wrong and can't find a clear answer on stackoverflow. I feel like this is an extremely simple test.

Here is my function:

```
public hello(name: string) {
  return 'Hello ' + name
}
```

Here is my Test:

```
let hello = jest.fn()
jest.mock('./myfile.ts', () => {
  return hello
})

beforeEach(() => {
  hello('world')
})

describe('hello test', (){
  it('expects to return concatenated string', () => {
    expect(hello.mock.results[0].value).toBe('Hello world') // returns as undefined - Test fails
  })
})
```

I keep getting undefined for the mock.results instead of 'Hello world'.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I'm overlooking something very simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to mock a function that you want to test. You should only mock other dependencies.

This is sufficient:

```
expect(hello('world')).toBe('Hello world')
```

Comment: Looks like it works! I had implemented some other code that caused issues. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Actually it's highly inefficient. If Expect returned a true or false boolean it could be wrapped into a custom framework method that would perform additional actions (highlight elements or text in red) based on the return value.